# How to see if a something in Graphics2D is off the frame

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, graphics2d

I have a `paint` method that I have draw a rectangle and move it across the screen and what I want it to do I when the rectangle goes off the screen to move it back to the start of the JFrame. I assume it would be something like `if(rectangle.isoffthescreen){ put it back on the screen }` but I don't know how to do that. Also, I want to know if you can do something to the rect like `JFrame frame = new JFrame();`, but for obviously for the rectangle. I'm sorry if this is confusing.

@MadProgrammer Here is where I am at so far

```
public class main extends JPanel {

public static int place = -350;
public Rectangle rect;
public int xDelta;
   public main() {

       rect = new Rectangle(0, 75, 50, 50);
       xDelta = 4;
       Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               rect.x += xDelta;
               if (rect.x + rect.width > getWidth() - 1) {
                   rect.x = getWidth() - rect.width;
                   xDelta *= -1;
               } else if (rect.x < 0) {
                   rect.x = 0;
                   xDelta *= -1;
               }
               repaint();
           }
       });
       timer.start();

   }

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    Random r = new Random();
    int r1;

    r1 = r.nextInt(5);
    if (r1 == 0) {
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    } else if (r1 == 1) {
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    } else if (r1 == 2) {
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
    } else if (r1 == 3) {
        g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    } else if (r1 == 4) {
        g2d.setColor(Color.PINK);
    } else {
        g2d.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    }

    place += 50;

    rect = new Rectangle(place, 100, 300, 200);
    g2d.draw(rect);
    g2d.fill(rect);
    g2d.dispose();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(400);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    repaint();

}
}
```

and

```
public class frame {

public static JFrame frame;


public static void main(String args[]){
    frame = new JFrame();   
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    main m = new main();
    m.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frame.add(m);
}


}
```

I still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of, you should avoid overriding `paint` of top level containers and instead use something the extends from `JComponent` (like `JPanel`) and override it's `paintComponent`.

There are a number of reasons, but in your case, the frame contains a decoration which sits inside the viewable area.

The basic process would be to check edge cases...

```
if (box.x + box.width > getWidth() - 1) {
    // The boxes right edge is beyond the right edge of it's container
} else if (box.x < 0) {
    // The boxes left edge is beyond the left edge of it's container
}
```

This checks to see if the `box`'s right edge is beyond the containers right edge and if the `box`'s left edge is beyond the left edge of the container.

It would be a simple process to included vertical checking as well.

**Updated with example**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Move {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Move();
    }

    public Move() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Rectangle box;
        private int xDelta;

        public TestPane() {

            box = new Rectangle(0, 75, 50, 50);
            xDelta = 4;
            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    box.x += xDelta;
                    if (box.x + box.width > getWidth() - 1) {
                        box.x = getWidth() - box.width;
                        xDelta *= -1;
                    } else if (box.x < 0) {
                        box.x = 0;
                        xDelta *= -1;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2d.fill(box);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

**Update from OP's example code**

Immediately, a number of things worry me...

1. Overriding `paint`
2. Calling `Thread.sleep` in the `paint` method
3. Calling `repaint` from within the `paint` method
4. Creating a new `Rectangle` in the `paint` method
5. The reliance on the `place` variable

Check out [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about painting in Swing

You should never block or perform long running processing the Event Dispatching Thread, this will prevent the EDT from processing (amongst other things) paint requests and new events.  By calling `Thread.sleep` in the `paint` method, you are preventing Swing from updating the screen.

Check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Calling `repaint` (or any method that might call `repaint`) within a `paint` method is a sure way to consume you CPU cycle.

You may want to check out [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details about the paint process in Swing

By creating a new `Rectangle` in the `paint` method, you are throwing away any changes that the `Timer` has made, effectively stopping you rectangle from moving effectively...

The `place` method is not required.  Animation is the illusion of change over time, hence the use of the `Timer` and `xDelta`.

**Updated based on your code example**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Move {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Move();
    }

    public Move() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new Main());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class Main extends JPanel {

        public static int place = -350;
        public Rectangle rect;
        public int xDelta;

        public Main() {

            rect = new Rectangle(0, 75, 50, 50);
            xDelta = 4;
            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    rect.x += xDelta;
                    if (rect.x + rect.width > getWidth() - 1) {
                        rect.x = getWidth() - rect.width;
                        xDelta *= -1;
                    } else if (rect.x < 0) {
                        rect.x = 0;
                        xDelta *= -1;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            Random r = new Random();
            int r1;

            r1 = r.nextInt(5);
            if (r1 == 0) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            } else if (r1 == 1) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            } else if (r1 == 2) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            } else if (r1 == 3) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            } else if (r1 == 4) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.PINK);
            } else {
                g2d.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            }

//            place += 50;

//            rect = new Rectangle(place, 100, 300, 200);
            g2d.draw(rect);
            g2d.fill(rect);
            g2d.dispose();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason when I use `paintComponent`it does not work, only `paint`. Is it bad to use `paint`.

Comment: In the if statement, what do I actually put in there to move the rectangle back?

Comment: @DilanHanrahan That's because top level containers don't have a `paintComponent` method.  Top level containers are also not double buffered.  Also, did you see the example?

Comment: @DilanHanrahan You have some fundamental mistakes in your code example.  I've updated with explanation and example